# continuity (by definition) at a point on piece-wise functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x^2 & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\ -2x^2 & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases} \quad$

I want to show continuity.

Here is my attempt at a proof:

We have that $f(x)$ is continuous away from $0$, so it suffices to prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0 = 0$.

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1} \subset \mathbb{R}$  be a sequence of points s.t $x_n \underset{n \to \infty}\to 0$

We have that $f(0) = 0$. Since $f(x_n) \underset{n \to \infty}\to 0$, we conclude continuity.

Request:

Please walk me through the steps and explanations very simply.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around continuity, specifically

1. why we have to show it just at the "piecewise" point (even with the non-strict inequality on one end)
2. how I calculated the limit of $f(x_n)$. In particular, since it is a piece-wise function, and it could be alternating.

I'm looking for a logical, rigorous proof technique that I can abstract and use in the future for similar problems.

I’d also like an understanding of (2), as that is where I am struggling in this proof.

Comment: Why don't you use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity?

Comment: If you have an easy way to do that @geetha290krm I would be open to learning it, but I’d also be interested mostly in knowing how I can conclude the limit of an alternating sequence on a piece-wise. That is my primary question/stuck-point here.

Comment: $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-0|<\sqrt {\frac {\epsilon} 2}$.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ satisfies

$$ (a_n)\to 0 \iff (|a_n|)\to 0 $$

So to prove that $$(f(x_n)) \to 0$$

It is sufficient to prove that

$$(|f(x_n)|)\to 0 $$

But for any $x$, $$|f(x)| = 2x^2$$

And since $2x^2$ is a polynomial, it is continuous (it seems from your question that this is something you can use in your course) so we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}2(x_n)^2 = 2\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\right)^2 = 2(0)^2 = 0 $$

Thus

$$(f(x_n)) \to 0 $$

Comment: Can you please also explain the "piecewise" point bit and an explanation on that?

Comment: @user129393192 The whole point of my answer is to show that in this case we can easily turn it into a limit of a regular non-piecewise polynomial, but if there is a specific step in here that you would like expanded I shall do so. If you want a general prodecdure for solving for limits of piecewise functions, consider asking a new question

Comment: My question was stated for (1), of why we only have to show it at that point to prove continuity and an explanation on that